# Get a specific option in HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

is possible get with HtmlAgilityPack a specific option? For example I've a select like this:

```
<select id="foo">
   <option value="0">1</option>
   <option value="1" selected="selected">2</option> 
</selected>
```

I need to get the option with selected. I know how to get the option with:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@id='foo']//option");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@id='foo']/option[@selected='selected']");
```

You can read more about xpath [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)

Comment: since you will be needing only one node, try using doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//select[@id='foo']/option[@selected='selected']");

Comment: nope, also with the last not working, have you tried?

Comment: I can't test it right now, but the logic is correct. Maybe you are working with the wrong document?

Answer (score 1):

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//Select[@id='foo']//*[@selected='selected']");
```

This should work but its giving a wider birth to get it by attempting to get the first node it finds of any Tag type at any depth within the select Tag that has a selected Attribute of selected value.

Answer (score 0):

if the html looks like this

```
<option value="1" selected>2</option>
```

it should be like this

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//Select[@id='foo']//*[@selected='']");
```